# Usefulness of a/b test if we already know we must implement the feature

Tags: ab-test

The situation is as follows. Because of compliance reasons, we must implement a change to our registration flow. Party A says: We must run an a/b test so that we understand the effect of that change. Party B says: Implementing the a/b test costs time, and thus money. We must implement the change anyway or else we will be fined, so whatever the result of the test will be, we cannot revert the changes. Running an a/b test is thus close to useless.

Which party is right and why?

Comment: Wouldn’t it be useful to understand the expected effect of this change?

Comment: So let's say the change is to add an x number of fields to the registration flow. We expect that this increases friction, and thus that less people will finish the registration flow. However, these fields are mandatory. If we do not ask for the information, we risk hefty fines. So even if we know EXACTLY the change, what would it change? Would we need an a/b test for that? Couldn't we just look at the data before and after? And if we see that indeed, as expected, number of registrations dropped, then we can have an a/b test for two versions that both include the mandatory new fields?

Comment: Maybe I can elaborate a little bit more. Let's say we expect the number of registrations to drop by 20%. The a/b test shows us it is indeed 20%. Great. Now what? What if we expect 20%, but we get 40%. Great! Why did we expect 20% anyway? And what do we do now that we know it's 40%? We cannot remove those fields. And we would have seen the same results just looking at before and after data.

Comment: So go into the new era totally clueless about what to expect?

Comment: Exactly. Because the new era is mandatory. We must go there. So why invest time and money in an a/b test? If the results are unsatisfactory, what are we gonna do about it?

Comment: It's like, if the government decides that now citizens must provide additional information x and y when opening a bank account, or else the bank will get a big fine, would a bank want to test through an a/b test what asking for that extra information does with users opening a new bank account? What are they going to do if less people open a bank account? Not ask for that information? :)

Comment: The bank can make changes elsewhere in the business to make up for anticipated losses due to this change.